# Which is the object of a long sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Teachers accordingly made students’ need, not textual and historical accuracy, their supreme interest, chopping dangerous texts into short phrases, and using these to impart lessons extemporaneously on a variety of subjects, from syntax to science.

From this long sentence, I’m not sure especially of the object. Is “their supreme interest” the object? But it doesn’t make sense when combining “made student’s need”. How should I understand this sentence clearly?

Here is my division of this sentence.

**Teachers accordingly made students’ need,** (not textual and historical accuracy,) **their supreme interest,** (chopping dangerous texts into short phrases, and using these to impart lessons extemporaneously on a variety of subjects, from syntax to science.)

Thanks for helping me analyze it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object is **students' need**.

> Their supreme interest *was what*?
>   Their supreme interest was **students' need**.

Comment: Oh thanks!! I don't know why I was confused by this sentence...